# How to get access to the default variable of the role from another role in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a role with default calculating variables like:

```
port: {{prefix}}{{postfix}}
```

When I try to get access to this variable from another role  with `{{hostvars[broker]['port']}}` , I catch error:

```
AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'port'
```

In most cases, I need to calculate port, but in rare cases, I need to override this var from host-var.
What is the best way to get access to default var from another role?

Ansible version: 2.2.0.0

Comment: You should not depend on defaults of another role. When you build roles with equal variables, try to give them the same name, so you can define them once for both roles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `{{hostvars[broker]['port']}}` you can access only host facts and role defaults are not facts, so this will work only if you define port as host-var.

If you absolutely need to query port value from other plays/hosts after applying your role to `broker` host, you may add to your role:

```
- set_fact:
    port: "{{ port }}"
```

this will ensure that there is `port` fact exist so you can access it via `hostvars`.